# android tess-two OCR speed up and error

Tags: java, android, ocr, tess-two

The OCR in my application is very slow

How can I speed up my application

and I have some error when the code executes

This is my code of OCR

```
public class ProcessImage extends AsyncTask<String,String, String> {
    String OCRresult = null;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {


        try {

            mTess.setImage(OCR.image);
            OCRresult = mTess.getUTF8Text();
            mTess.end();
            mTess.clear();

        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            Log.e("OcrRecognizeAsyncTask",
                    "Caught RuntimeException in request to Tesseract. Setting state to CONTINUOUS_STOPPED.",
                    e);

            try {

            } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
                // Continue
            }
            return null;
        }

        return "Executed";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(OCRTextView);
        txt.setText("請按返回"); // txt.setText(result);
        if(OCRresult!=null) {
            txt.setText(OCRresult);
        }
        // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
        // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}



}
```

This the error when code executes

[This the error when code executes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z3VV.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not call clear() after end(). If you want to speed up the detection check the image size and play with the detector params and detection modes.

Good luck.

Comment: Thka for your answer  I would try it